# ajax is not responding

Tags: php, ajax

I am designing a web application. It was working all fine before adding ajax. Now i want to add ajax but nothing is happening same first page is loading again and again. Please tell me the reason why ajax is not responding (no error message no new page loading). My code is below.
h.php is a simple file saying hello.

first.php:

```
<html>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
 <head>
      <title>Online library </title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/style.css" />
<form method="post">
<div class="result"></div>
UserName:<input type="text" name="name" id="username"><br><br>
Password:<input type="password" name="password" id="password"><br><br>
<button id="loginn" type="submit" name="button" <strong>login</strong> </button>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src=""jquery-3.2.0.js""></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

     $("#loginn").submit(function(e){   
         var  username=$("#username").val();
         var  password=$("#password").val();
         var result=$('.result').val();
         var dataString = 'username='+username+'&password='+password;
          $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "log.php",
            data: dataString,
           success: function(responseText){    
            if(responseText==0)    {

            result.html('<span class="error">incorrect username</span>');
            }
        else if(responseText==1)
            {
              window.location="h.php";
           }
        else{
              alert('error in query');
             }
           }
          });

        e.preventDefault();
    });
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

log.php:

```
<?php
include 'user.php';
$name=$_POST["username"]; 
$password=$_POST["password"];
$con=new users();
$con->login($name,$password);
?>
```

user.php:

```
<?php

class users
{
public function constructs()
{
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die (mysqli_error());
mysqli_select_db($con,'online') or die(mysqli_error($con));
return $con;
}

 function login($username, $password) {
$con=$this->constructs();
$rs = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT username, password FROM member WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($rs)>0)
{
echo 1;
}
else {
echo 0;
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Where does the execution fail? You are open to SQL injections and need to hash your passwords.

Comment: `function constructs()` you sure you didn't mean `function __construct()`?

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src=""jquery-3.2.0.js"">` that's a syntax error, one being "off-topic" I might add. Look at your developer console and use php's error reporting.

Comment: @chris85 it is the requirement of project that it should be open to attacks. Execution fails mean nothing is happening on clicking login button .

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes i am sure its constructs and this syntax error is in posting code here. Sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

You're tying your code to the document.ready function from jQuery which runs your code immediately when the document is ready to render, but that's only part of the problem I think. Also try adding some console.log lines in your code in various places to check to make sure document references are working correctly.

Your code that you pasted has some syntax errors in, especially your user.php file (if it's indeed copy/pasted directly). Even though the files may not print any results try loading each one in your browser to see if there are syntax errors.

Your html is formatted wrong in a few places in your first.php. Check the placement of your doctype, add the proper end tags for your <head> section, check your formatting for the form itself (specifically the login button itself)

---

is this actually part of your code?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src=""jquery-3.2.0.js""></script>
```

if so it should be

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.0.js"></script>
```

let me know if there's anything else

Comment: there is no syntax error as log and first were working quite well before ajax. The error you mentioned is in posting code here. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

There are alot of bugs in your code not to mention its very unsafe as the comments have stated. Here are a few things you are missing:

- Curly bracket at the end in `users.php`
- Jquery is not included properly in index file you have and extra `" "`
- You are listening for a submit event on a button instead of a form, change that to a click event
- Your results var inside the submit event dosent need the `val()` at the end you wont see the results from the query beacuase of that.

Providing that the database is setup correctly the rest of the code should work.

Here is the working code:

index.php

```
 $("#loginn").click(function(e){   
     var  username=$("#username").val();
     var  password=$("#password").val();
     var result=$('.result');
     var dataString = 'username='+username+'&password='+password;
      $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "log.php",
        data: dataString,
       success: function(responseText){   
        console.log(responseText); 
        if(responseText==0)    {

        $(result).html('<span class="error">incorrect username</span>');
        }
       else if(responseText==1)
        {
          window.location="h.php";
       }
        else{
          alert('error in query');
         }
       },
       fail: function(err) {
           console.log(err); 

       }
      });

    e.preventDefault();
});
});
```

log.php - the same

user.php - missing curly bracket at the end

Comment: Its requirement that it should be open to attack. Tried your code still not working. No syntax errors in original code. Is it a problem with my browser? I am using chrome with xampp.

Comment: I've tried the code before posting it worked for me. The only thing that springs to mind is that your database connection is not correctly established.

Comment: its still not working for me. I have tried without ajax and my database was working correctly. what do you think is wrong in my database connection??

Comment: You could be entering the wrong information required for the connection. Which means that you are probably not even connect to the database when running the code.